# How to achieve logical constness with the PIMPL idiom

Tags: c++11, constants, pimpl-idiom

Imagine a typical realization of the PIMPL idiom:

```
class ObjectImpl;

class Object
{
  Object(ObjectImpl* object_impl)
    : _impl(object_impl);

private:      
  ObjectImpl* _impl;
};
```

What I'm looking for is a way to reuse the same implementation to wrap a type T that's either ObjectImpl or const ObjectImpl but nothing else:

```
class ObjectImpl;

class Object
{
  Object(T* object_impl)
    : _impl(object_impl);

private:
  // T being either ObjectImpl or const ObjectImpl
  T* _impl;
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve is retaining logical constness through the PIMPL interface so that I'm disallowed by the compiler to call non-const methods on an Object wrapping a const ObjectImpl*.

It's basically just this trick borrowed from one of Scott Meyers Effective C++ books but with an added layer of abstraction:

```
struct SData
{
  const Data* data() const { return _data; }
  Data* data() { return _data; }

private:
  Data* _data:
};
```

Of course I could copy the entire class into a class ConstObject and have it wrap a const* Object instead of an Object* but I'm obviously trying to prevent code duplication.

I've also thought about templates but they seem a bit overkill for the task at hand. For one, I want T to only be either ObjectImpl or const ObjectImpl. Secondly, templates seem to work against the idea of PIMPL when exported as a DLL interface. Is there a better solution to go with?

Comment: There is nothing typical about a PIMPL that takes an implementation pointer in the constructor. PIMPL is supposed to be an implementation detail, invisible at the interface of the class.

Comment: That constructor could be private for internal purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRTP.

```
template<class Storage>
struct const_Object_helper {
  Storage* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  Storage const* self() const { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
  // const access code goes here, get it via `self()->PImpl()`
};
struct const_Object: const_Object_helper<const_Object> {
  const_Object( objectImpl const* impl ):pImpl(impl) {}
private:
  objectImpl const* pImpl = nullptr;
  objectImpl const* PImpl() const { return pImpl; }
  template<class Storage>
  friend struct const_Object_helper;
};
struct Object: const_Object_helper<Object> {
  // put non-const object code here
  Object( objectImpl* impl ):pImpl(impl) {}
  operator const_Object() const {
    return {PImpl()}; // note, a copy/clone/rc increase may be needed here
  }
private:
  objectImpl* pImpl = nullptr;
  objectImpl const* PImpl() const { return pImpl; }
  objectImpl* PImpl() { return pImpl; }
  template<class Storage>
  friend struct const_Object_helper;
};
```

This is the zero runtime overhead version, but requires the implementation of `const_Object_helper` and `Object_helper` to be exposed.  As it just involves forwarding stuff to the actual impl, this seems relatively harmless.

You can remove that need by replacing the CRTP part of the helpers with a pure-virtual `objectImpl const* get_pimpl() const = 0` and `objectImpl* get_pimpl() = 0`, then implement them in the derived types.

Another, somewhat crazy, approach would be to use an `any` augmented with type-erased operations (you also want to teach the type erasure mechanism about `const`, and that a `super_any` with fewer interfaces can be implicitly converted over without doing another layer of wrapping).

Here we define certain operations, say print and dance and boogie:

```
auto const print = make_any_method<void(std::ostream&), true>(
  [](auto&&self, std::ostream& s) {
    s << decltype(self)(self);
  }
);
auto const dance = make_any_method<void()>(
  [](auto&&self) {
    decltype(self)(self).dance();
  }
);
auto const dance = make_any_method<double(), true>(
  [](auto&&self) {
    return decltype(self)(self).boogie();
  }
);
```

Now we create two types:

```
using object = super_any< decltype(print), decltype(dance), decltype(boogie) > object;
using const_object = super_any< decltype(print), decltype(boogie) >;
```

Next, augment the `super_any` with the ability to assign-from sources with strictly weaker requirements.

Our `object o;` can `(o->*dance)()`.  Our `const_object co;` can `double d = (co->*boogie)();`.

Anything can be stored in an `object` that supports the operations described by `print`, `boogie` and `dance`, plus the requirements of `any` (copy, destroy, assign).  Anything at all.

Similarly, the `const_object` supports anything that can be described by `print` and `boogie` and copy/destroy/assign.

Derived types from `object` or `const_object` can add operator overloading features easily.

This technique is advanced.  You can use `boost::type_erasure` to do it, probably slicker than this sketch.

Comment: Hope I'm not bugging you, but could I ask what would be the problem with [this trivial solution](https://ideone.com/aZR44A)? Many thanks.

Comment: @AmiTavory You cannot construct a `ConstObject` from a `const ObjectImpl`.  And you are missing stuff (nothing fundamental) like `operator ConstObject`.  That is about it.

Comment: The question author is also worried about the DLL interface export with templates. Does the CRTP also solves this issue ?

Comment: @Aurelien There are two template instances that will be exported -- `const_Object_helper<const_Object> ` and `const_Object_helper<Object> `.  Manually exporting exactly two templates from a DLL is possible on windows (I have done it).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following general design pattern. It wastes an additional pointer, but will enforce the requirement that the `const` object will be able to only access `const` methods of the private object:

```
class ObjectImpl;

class const_Object {

public:

  const_Object(const ObjectImpl* object_impl)
    : _impl(object_impl);

  // Only const methods

private:      
  const ObjectImpl* _impl;
};

class Object : public const_Object
{
  Object(ObjectImpl* object_impl)
    : const_Object(object_impl), _impl(object_impl);

  // non-const methods go here.

private:      
  ObjectImpl* _impl;
};
```

Comment: I've thought about sth very similar, like implementing Object as usual, then doing class ConstObject : public Object { private: const ObjectImpl* _impl; } shadowing the base class member. Seemed somewhat hacky and ugly though. Your solution definitely seems nicer.

Comment: This duplicates the pointer.  This violates DRY, uses resources, and opens up a whole host of possible bugs.  For example `Object foo(blah); const_Object bar(newt); const_Object& foo_const=foo; foo_const=bar;` just sliced `foo` and made it point to two pImpls.